# I want to add each custom icons to my expandable listview header but it is taking only the first icon

Tags: expandablelistview

animationSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Animation animationSlideInLeft, android.R.anim.slide_in_left); error showing ' , ' or ) is expected please help

Comment: This is not a question ...

Comment: animationSlideInLeft = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left); Error:(42, 46) error: method loadAnimation in class AnimationUtils cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,int
found: HomeFragment,int
reason: actual argument HomeFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion  this is the original question yes it is silly but for me new to this is time consuming..solution is appreciated